# Using Tos"r"Us, how do I get the index of the image being shown when using the slider callback function, tosrus

Tags: jquery

When using [Tos"R"Us](http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/), how do I get the current or next index of the collection of images that the the slider callback function is using when displaying the next slide.  I want to do something like this so I can eventually do it for Google Analytics.

```
var tos = $("#myVar a").tosrus();
tos.bind("sliding.tos", function( event ) {
  alert(slides[index])
});
```

I know this may be a little, "beginner", but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/custom-events.php). it can be achieved like so:-

```
var tos = $("#myVar a").tosrus();
tos.bind("sliding.tos", function( event, currentIndex) {
  alert(currentIndex);
});
```

Note: the index is zero based.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much